# Getting "undefined is not and object" in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, state

So what I want is to have a list of TouchableOpacities which represent the days of the following week. The idea is, when I press any given day, its style changes between "selected" and "unselected"

[Card with desired buttons for days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V9A9.png)

My understanding is that (and I'm kind of a newbie), to force the component to re-render when I want the style to change, I must change the state. And this state should be in the parent component, whose code is the following:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import DaySelector from "./DaySelector";

const WeekList = () => {
  const [activeDays, setActiveDays] = useState([]);

  function onClick(index) {
    let days = [...activeDays];
    let day = days[index];
    days[index].active = !day.active;
    setActiveDays(days);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let date = new Date();
    let tempArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      let temp = new Date();
      temp.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
      tempArr.push({
        key: temp.getDay(),
        day: temp,
        active: true,
        onPress: () => onClick(i),
      });
    }

    setActiveDays(tempArr);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {activeDays.map((day) => (
        <DaySelector
          key={day.key}
          day={day.day}
          active={day.active}
          onClick={day.onPress}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default WeekList;
```

However, I keep getting the error in the title: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'day.active')", refering to line 10 of the 'onClick' (let day = days[index];) function, whose job is to toggle the "active" property the object, which should then propagate to the component, where a simple ternary operator uses it to choose the style to apply.

The thing is, I've console.logged the hell out of the program and it either works (but doesn't actually change the style of the DaySelector component) or it crashes, despite the logs saying "day" is indeed an object.

In short, I don't know what I'm doing wrong... and it seemed so simple at the beginning...
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the onPress function on the object state seemed fishy to me. So I rewrote it without that and it works.

```
  /**
   * Define the behavior of the component here.
   * Keep on data on the state.
   */
  const onClick = (index: number) => {
    // Update a field in an object in a list _without mutating_ the objects.
    setActiveDays([
      ...activeDays.slice(0, index),
      { ...activeDays[index], active: !activeDays[index].active },
      ...activeDays.slice(index + 1),
    ]);
  };

// Then

{activeDays.map((day: any, i: number) => (
 <DaySelector
  key={day.key}
  day={day.day}
  active={day.active}
  onClick={() => onClick(i)}
 />
))}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks! But could you expand on what makes it "fishy" to pass a function to the object-state? Clearly the error was there, but I don't get why...

Comment: It's a good question. First of all, a component should be reactive to the state of its system, and that state should be represented as simply as possible. Ie, store the simplest possible values to describe a component’s state. Functions (and components) are behavioural and should not be included in react state. Secondly, functions are not normal data objects, they rely on lexical scope. What happens to that scope when you put it on state? I'm not sure, but it probably loses "access" to symbols included in the function.

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes sense. Thanks, @windowsill